# Natural language word replacing in PHP

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I have an array of words like:

```
$matchWords = ['a','is','of'];
```

And a text like:

> "This is a test text. Test, comma instead of space."

I need to replace all occurrences of the words in $wordsArray in the text for the following html:

```
<span style="color:red;">$wordMatched</span>
```

The other words I need to replace with a tags.

So basically my problems resume to:

- **Match only worlds** (if I search for the word "a" and not the letter
  "a";
- **Don't match anything inside html a** and **span** tags;

So, I the following code so far:

```
$wordsArray = ['this','is','a','test','text','comma','instead','of','space'];
$matches = ['a','is','of'];
$text = "This is a test text. Test, comma instead of space.";

foreach($wordsArray as $word){
    if(in_array($word, $matches)){
        $known[] = '(^|[.!?: ;,])'.$word.'([.!?: ;,]|$)';
    }
    else{
        $notKnown[] = '(^|[.!?: ;,])'.$word.'([.!?: ;,]|$)';
    }
}

// Known
$wordList = implode('|', $known);
$text = preg_replace('/('.$wordList.')/', '<span>$1</span>', $text);

// Not Known
$wordList = implode('|', $notKnown);
$text = preg_replace('/('.$wordList.')/', '<a href="texts/addWord&word=$1" class="info label">$1</a>', $text);
```

This doesn't work as it adds the spaces and delimiter to my matches.

To be quite honest I don't understand much of regex in php so if anyone could help me out here it would be great.

Thanks

--EDIT--
After xdazz answer I tested the following text and the following came out:

> Hi,
>
> This is aa a a a a test of some span thing.
>
> Is it really working?

Output:

```
<a class="wordLink info label" href="texts/addWord&word=Hi">Hi</a>,<br />
<br />
<a class="wordLink info label" href="texts/addWord&word=This">This</a> <<a class="wordLink info label" href="texts/addWord&word=span">span</a> style="color:red;">is</<a class="wordLink info label" href="texts/addWord&word=span">span</a>> <a class="wordLink info label" href="texts/addWord&word=aa">aa</a> <<a class="wordLink info label" href="texts/addWord&word=span">span</a> style="color:red;">a</<a class="wordLink info label" href="texts/addWord&word=span">span</a>> <<a class="wordLink info label" href="texts/addWord&word=span">span</a> style="color:red;">a</<a class="wordLink info label" href="texts/addWord&word=span">span</a>> <<a class="wordLink info label" href="texts/addWord&word=span">span</a> style="color:red;">a</<a class="wordLink info label" href="texts/addWord&word=span">span</a>> <<a class="wordLink info label" href="texts/addWord&word=span">span</a> style="color:red;">a</<a class="wordLink info label" href="texts/addWord&word=span">span</a>> <a class="wordLink info label" href="texts/addWord&word=test">test</a> <<a class="wordLink info label" href="texts/addWord&word=span">span</a> style="color:red;">of</<a class="wordLink info label" href="texts/addWord&word=span">span</a>> <a class="wordLink info label" href="texts/addWord&word=some">some</a> <a class="wordLink info label" href="texts/addWord&word=span">span</a> <<a class="wordLink info label" href="texts/addWord&word=span">span</a> style="color:red;">thing</<a class="wordLink info label" href="texts/addWord&word=span">span</a>>.<br />
<br />
<a class="wordLink info label" href="texts/addWord&word=Is">Is</a> <<a class="wordLink info label" href="texts/addWord&word=span">span</a> style="color:red;">it</<a class="wordLink info label" href="texts/addWord&word=span">span</a>> <a class="wordLink info label" href="texts/addWord&word=really">really</a> <a class="wordLink info label" href="texts/addWord&word=working">working</a>?
```

I think the problem is around span tag. Other than that all seems good.

Comment: searching for `a` is going to lead to things like `me<span>a</span>t`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this:

```
$matchWords = array('a','is','of'); 
$text = "This is a test text. Test, comma instead of space.";
$text = preg_replace('/\b('.implode('|', $matchWords).')\b/', '<span style="color:red;">$1</span>', $text);
```

Comment: This answer my plus one as the answer is otherwise excellent, but I think this solution will match the `a` in `"This is <a href...> test` which the OP said should not match.  I think changing to this will help that: `$matchWords = array('(?<!\<)a','is','of');`.  This adds a "lookaround" to the `a`, to confirm it's not preceded by an `<`.  The resultant regex then looks like `'/\b((?<!\<)a|is|of)\b/'`

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I tested with another text just to make sure and it gave me some issues. Please see my original question this update

Comment: @jribeiro I don't think that's a regex problem per se, I think it's because you're applying one regex to the result of the other.  Try this regex in isolation to confirm it works on its own and does what it needs to do, then work from there.

Comment: Very true. It seems to work. Just not sure I need the extra regex. it seems to provide the same results both ways.